# How to force my whole package to use a __future__ directive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I place:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

inside `__init__.py` on the top level dir on my package and garantee that the absolute_import will be applied to all code that runs inside that package or sub-packages?

Or should I put that directive in each model that does an absolute import?

I maintain a Python package and I'm trying to keep my code as easy as possible to migrate to Python3 when the time comes. I can't do it right away because my dependencies are not on Python3 yet.

Comment: '2to3' will fix them for you when you do want to change over.

Comment: @katrielalex: Where "fixing" means "removing", which wouldn't even be necessary, since Python 3 simply ignores all current `__future__` imports.

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.5, for the first time since Python 2.6, a new `__future__` directive `generator_stop` has been introduced.  [See PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `__future__` imports are only valid for a single file.  You will have to put this line at the top of every Python source file.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#future):

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python.